# Replace [gap] with [gap-system], [gaps-in-data], and [gaps-in-visuals]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-block-request

The tag wiki for [gap](/questions/tagged/gap) refers to the [computer algebra system GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/).  However, many of the questions with [gap](/questions/tagged/gap) actually refer to gaps in data in tables, matrices, and other data structures.  Some of the questions also refer to gaps around frames in webpages, and other "visual gaps".  Out of 80 questions with [gap](/questions/tagged/gap), only these three: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1270394/370246) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9100134/370246) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9506705/370246) appear to actually refer to the computer algebra system.

How should we solve the mess that is [gap](/questions/tagged/gap)?

Comment: The motivation for this question and the three linked questions came from @DouglasS.Stones [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9073/do-we-actually-welcome-questions-about-software-that-mathematicians-use) on meta.math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be that collisions among different meanings of "gap" are very likely, so "gap" is probably not a good name for a tag.  I suggest that we use [gap-system](/questions/tagged/gap-system) for GAP, introduce two other tags, e.g. [gaps-in-data](/questions/tagged/gaps-in-data) and [gaps-in-visuals](/questions/tagged/gaps-in-visuals) for the other two common uses of [gap](/questions/tagged/gap), and then blacklist [gap](/questions/tagged/gap).

---

**Update:** All of the questions that used to have [gap](/questions/tagged/gap) have been re-tagged. [gap](/questions/tagged/gap) hasn't been blacklisted, but if the problem happens again then we'll suggest blacklisting it.

Comment: The [gap-system] proposal matches the GAP url: [www.gap-system.org](http://www.gap-system.org/), which makes it particularly suitable.

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple Suggesting edits may be your best bet. Link to this discussion in the edit summary for reference. You seem to have the best handle on what questions should be tagged with what, so waiting for someone else to do the edits is probably a waste of time.

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple Done.

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple Oops, I missed the gap-system one. It should be fixed now. Happy retagging!

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple I'd wait until it becomes a problem again. [tag:gap] will disappear by itself in 24 hours, and then we'll see what happens.